# First notification after turn on display this site has been updated in the background

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging, react-tsx

When implementing FCM  in the context of a PWA, there might be an issue where the first notification fails to display, accompanied by the message "The site has been updated in the background." This usually occurs when the application hasn't been used for a certain period or when the device is restarted.

The second notification onward displays correctly, suggesting that the service worker may not be ready to receive the first notification. Attempts to implement a message queue system to wait for the service worker to be ready before displaying the notification have been unsuccessful.

```
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.0/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.0/firebase-messaging.js');

async function initializeFirebase() {
  try {
    const response = await fetch('apiUrl');

    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error(`HTTP error! Status: ${response.status}`);
    }

    const responseText = await response.text();
    const data = await JSON.parse(responseText).data;

    firebase.initializeApp(data.fireBaseConf);
    messaging = firebase.messaging();

    messaging.onBackgroundMessage(async function (payload) {
      const notificationTitle = payload.data.title;
      const notificationOptions = { 
        body: payload.data.body,
        image: payload.data?.image,
        data: payload.data
      };
      return await self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle, notificationOptions);
  });

  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error initializing Firebase:', error);
  }
}

initializeFirebase()


var CACHE_NAME = 'pwa-task-manager';
var urlsToCache = [
];

self.addEventListener('install', event => {
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.open(CACHE_NAME)
      .then(function (cache) {
        return cache.addAll(urlsToCache);
      })
  );
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', event => {
  event.respondWith(
    caches.match(event.request)
      .then(function (response) {
        if (response) {
          return response;
        }
        return fetch(event.request);
      }
      )
  );
});

self.addEventListener('activate', event => {
  var cacheWhitelist = ['pwa-task-manager'];
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.keys().then(cacheNames => {
      return Promise.all(
        cacheNames.map(cacheName => {
          if (cacheWhitelist.indexOf(cacheName) === -1) {
            return caches.delete(cacheName);
          }
        })
      );
    })
  );
});

self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function (event) {
  const redirectUrl = event.notification.data?.urlRedirect
  event.notification.close();
  if (redirectUrl) {
    event.waitUntil(
      clients.openWindow(redirectUrl)
    );
  }
});
```

If anyone has any leads or has encountered this issue during the deployment of a PWA and FCM, please feel free to share your insights or experiences.

Best regards.

I tried implementing a message queue system to wait for the service worker to be ready before displaying the notification, but without success. I also attempted to synchronize it with the subscription :

```
const subscription = await self.registration.pushManager.getSubscription();
      if (subscription) {
        return await self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle, notificationOptions);
      }
  });
```